# Unable to Pass Two Parameters as Argument to Javascript Function

Tags: karate

I am trying to use karate.call to invoke function of a JS file receiving two arguments (String, Array of String). However the array of string would not be passed on to the JS file.

The JS file contains:

```
function(query, fragments) {
// Here lies some code
// One of them includes fragments.length;
}
```

And I call the JS function on another JS file in this way:

```
//var query = 'Some string';
//var fragments = ['fragment1', 'fragment2'];
var clean = karate.call('../helper/helper.js', [query, fragments]);
```

I am able to pass query which is a string. But I was unable to pass the array of string. The error says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined
```

It seems the array of string did not get passed to the JS function. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your `.call()` only passes one parameter, that array you build from `query` and `fragments`.  If you used `.apply()` instead of `.call()` that would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read you function first and invoke is just like any other js function

```
var myFun = karate.read('../helper/helper.js');
var funCall = myFun(query, fragments);
```

or

```
 var myCall = karate.read('../helper/helper.js')(query, fragments);
```

this should work.

Answer (score 2):

`.call` takes parameters as comma separated values , you need to use `.apply` if you want to pass values as an array.

```
var clean = karate.call('../helper/helper.js', query, fragments);
```

will work...

Comment: This does not work as karate complains javascript function call failed: ```TypeError: Can not invoke method [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.OverloadedDynamicMethod Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.call(String,Object) Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.call(String) ] with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures.```

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are missing an important clarification:

I often do single arg functions like:

```
* def concatParams =
  """
  function(s) {
    return "urldt=" + todaysDate + "&caseid=" + s.caseid
  } 
  """
```

And I  will call that like so:

```
* def params = call concatParams {caseid: '3433344'}
```

But, when I want to do 2 params, I will define a function like so:

```
* def concatParams =
  """
  function(d,s) {
    return "urldt=" + d.date + "&caseid=" + s.caseid
  } 
  """
```

And unintuitively, neither of these will work:

```
* def params = call concatParams {date: '01/01/2020', caseid: '3433344'}
* def params = call concatParams '01/01/2020' '3433344'
```

To get it to work, instead I call it like this:

```
* def params = concatParams('01/01/2020', '3433344')
```

Documentation does not clarify this.

Comment: you are wrong. the documentation DOES clarify this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#javascript-functions

Comment: Uhm. Your case is different than the one I asked here.Like Peter said, I have no problem passing params like regular JS functions when it is declared inside a feature

Answer (score 0):

`call` method accepts comma separated params and `apply` accept array so you need to replace `call` into `apply`. your code looks like

```
function karate(query, fragments) {
// Here lies some code
// One of them includes fragments.length;
}

var clean = karate.apply('../helper/helper.js', [query, fragments]);
```

Comment: I don't think there was a method of karate.apply(), as it is not available in the documentation too. I tried your recommendation and it says 

```karate.apply is not a function```

https://github.com/intuit/karate/

Comment: @Raymond please give a name to the function, the code is updated.

Comment: everyone: please ignore this answer, once you define a JS function, you can slap parentheses and arguments onto it just like NORMAL JS. what's worse, this example re-defines the built-in `karate` JS helper object

Answer (score 0):

```
 var clean = karate.call('../helper/helper.js', query, fragments);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: This does not work as karate complains javascript function call failed: ```TypeError: Can not invoke method [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.OverloadedDynamicMethod
Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.call(String,Object)
 Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.call(String)
] with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures.```